# SSIS | The file was not found error

Tags: ssis

I have created a package with an XML data source which is then exported to SQL Server.

1. If file does not exist in the source folder, job should stop process with
   `Success` Result.
2. If file does exist, process it and generate a report and then `Pass` or `fail` based on uploaded data.

When I added one step to the process which is checking if the file present in the folder:

If file exists in the folder, job works OK and generate all required files, etc.

If file does not exist, I get the following message:

> Error at Process XML - save to Preload table [OLE DB Destination [24]]: SSIS Error Code
>   DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The
>   AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager
>   "LocalHost.SSIS_TEST" failed with error code 0xC0014041.  There may be
>   error messages posted before this with more information on why the
>   AcquireConnection method call failed. Error at Process XML - save to
>   Preload table [SSIS.Pipeline]: OLE DB Destination failed validation
>   and returned error code 0xC020801C. Error at Process XML - save to
>   Preload table [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed
>   validation. Error at Process XML - save to Preload table: There were
>   errors during task validation. Error at Package: The connection
>   manager "LocalHost.SSIS_TEST" will not acquire a connection because
>   the connection manager OfflineMode property is TRUE. When the
>   OfflineMode is TRUE, connections cannot be acquired.

[Flow Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqqK5.jpg)

[Data Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2MFK.jpg)

Comment: Question was near me.  On Data Flow -> XML Source -> Properties -> Validate External Metadata need to be set to "False".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running this in Visual Studio / Bids and have Offline mode set to true?

Go to SSIS top level menu and deselect Work Offline.

Comment: Hello BIDeveloper. Checked, currently Propeerties OfflineMode set to "False". Seems found what caused this error. "Question was near me. On Data Flow -> XML Source -> Properties -> Validate External Metadata need to be set to "False"."

Answer (score 0):

For me, the Connection Manager tested ok, but I still had errors on the Data Flow items telling me the "AcquireConnection method call failed".  Somehow the Connection Manager was not being refreshed for the tasks.  I noticed at the bottom of the design screen in the Connection Managers section, the connection had a small red down arrow icon next to it.  Right-click that connection and select "Test Connectivity".  This refreshed the connections for the Data Flow items and the errors went away.